# Does a struct instance get created when storing the address of the struct definition into a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, embedded

In my microcontrollers course, we are writing embedded C for the SAMD20J18 microcontroller.

The beginning of our program contains the following two lines of code:

```
Port *ports = PORT_INSTS; 
PortGroup *porA = &(ports->Group[0]);
```

The second line implies to me that an instance of the `Port` struct exists since its `Group` member is being accessed. However, the course manual states that `PORT_INSTS` is the base address of the `Port` struct definition (shown below), rather than an instance of it. Is an instance of struct `Port` being created by storing the address of the struct definition in the pointer `ports`? It would make more sense to me that the `PORT_INSTS` address points to an existing instance of struct `Port`. Am I wrong or is the manual wrong?

Here is the relevant portion of the manual:

[image: manual]

Comment: `Port *ports = PORT_INSTS; ` that maps memory to `Port` struct, but it has to be initialized. Compiler doesn't create anything for you.

Comment: You can see that PORT_INSTS becomes PORTS, and PORTS is a hard-wired address.  You have to know — from the documentation — whether there is one port or a set of ports at that address.  Working with element 0 should be OK, but only studying the document can reassure about anything more.  Or direct experience with the hardware you're using, which I don't have.

Comment: Isn't the reason for such a struct pointer in the embedded world, to point to the register sets, which are memory mapped, and do not need to be created?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes. The portion i am not clear on is where this struct is being instantiated. I am assuming that from the struct definition, a variable of that struct must be instantiated that contains the register pointers. But I may be wrong with my understanding of how this works.

Comment: You should ask your tutor if he did not make clear what happens. That way he can improve his didactics and extend the course material. Oh, and: don't post images of text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is the same as :

```
Port *ports = (Port *)0x41004400UL;
```

The pointer `ports` points to storage that has the memory address `0x41004400`. The device hardware maps this address range to registers within the port controller. [Link to documentation](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Section2_GPIO.pdf)

Comment: Is it okay to say that at 0x41004400, there is an already existing structure of type `Port`?

Comment: @ByronS: In the context of hardware access, then yes; you're accessing memory-addressed I/O ports, and they're 'pre-allocated' by the hardware.  The device exists at the address (you hope); you can't allocate anything else at the same address.

Comment: @ByronS : More accurate perhaps to say that the definition of `Ports` matches the hardware register structure.  When a `Ports*` references the specific device register start address, the individual registers for that device may be accessed via that structure.  If a `Ports` object were instantiated in regular memory, it would serve little semantic purpose - it only makes sense when overlaying the hardware device whose register structure it represents.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you, your response has cleared this up for me.

Answer (score 2):

> The second line implies to me that an instance of the Port struct exists since its Group member is being accessed. However, the course manual states that PORT_INSTS is the base address of the Port struct definition (shown below), rather than an instance of it.

It is both of these things. The purpose of the struct is to create an abstraction layer on top of already present MCU hardware registers. The registers already exist in the hardware, from the given base address and onward. That's why you don't have to allocate anything.